# Remove element only when all things are true

Tags: jquery

Our current shopping cart will not allow us to exclude certain states from free shipping through their software, so I am trying to write a script to remove the free shipping section when a certain state is entered.

I've been at it for hours and cannot seem to find the answer anywhere online, or through testing. Anyone that could point me in the right direction would be my hero. I'm very new to jQuery, JavaScript and the like, so please forgive me if this is a stupid easy question.

```
<div>
<div>HONOLULU, <span id="state">OK</span> 96819</div>
<ul>
    <li>$0.00 - Free Shipping</li>
    <li>$16.39 - UPS Ground</li>
    <li>$21.50 - UPS 2nd Day Air®</li>
    <li>$36.39 - UPS Next Day Air®</li>
    <li>$0.77 - First Class Mail</li>
    <li>$6.26 - Priority Mail</li>
</ul>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if ($('#state:contains("HI" || "AK")')); {
    $('li:contains("$0.00")').remove();

} });
```

When you change `<li>$0.00 - Free Shipping</li>` to any other number it appears in the list like it should be, but no matter what state I have in `<span id="state">`, if there is `<li>$0.00 - Free Shipping</li>` in the list it is removed.

From all the research I've been doing my code *seems* right, but it's not working. [Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kpyy/).

Comment: Did you mean to put a semicolon at the end of your `if` line?  Although this will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Dracorat, my comment is not the answer.  You cannot have an `or` inside a selector like that.  As you can see below, users are not taking the time to read the other answers before responding.

Comment: @Dracorat, but the jsFiddle is **not working**.  Notice how the condition is `true` when it clearly should be `false`?  http://jsfiddle.net/9Kpyy/4/

Comment: You're right. Sorry bout that. I'll delete my (wrong) commentary above. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.  First, lose the `;` in your `if` statement.

It should just be:

```
if(condition){
    // code
}
```

Second, you can't use `||` like that.  You need to do it like this:

```
$('#state:contains("HI"),#state:contains("AK")')
```

Finally, doing `if($jQueryObject)` isn't what you want.  That will always be true.  You want to check the `.length`.

So, it should be like this:

```
if ($('#state:contains("HI"),#state:contains("AK")').length) {
    $('li:contains("$0.00")').remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million for not only answering my question, but also taking the time to point out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`:contains("HI" || "AK")` matches the exact string `"HI" || "AK"`, there is no OR.

```
if ( $('#state:contains(HI)').length || $('#state:contains(AK)').length)  {
    $('li:contains("$0.00")').remove();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SFfLD/1/)

**EDIT:**

And as @David points out in the comment below, to check if an element exists you have to check the length.

Comment: It’s worth noting that you need to check the length as well as in the example, because any jQuery selector will return *truey*.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
if ($('#state').text()=='HI' || $('#state').text()=='AK') {
        $('li:contains("$0.00")').remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Kpyy/2/

Comment: But it will only work with the exact text `HI` or `AK`, so it's **not** the same as using as `:contains()`. even a whitespace will throw that one off.